# How to use a Resource Image in Word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, embedded-resource

I'm working on a project that will auto-generate Word and HTML reports.  If they don't provide an Image to use in the header of the Word report, the customer wants to use their logo.  I have the logo stored in the resources of one of the projects as a .jpg.

The method to add a picture to a range needs the path as a string to the image, without any overloads.  I know that when a file is added to the resources of the project, it doesn't exist as it gets embedded inside the .dll that gets created.  Is there no way to utilize that embedded resource in that method?

Do I need to copy that file as part of the install to the directory?  I'm thinking that may be the easiest solution, however what should I do for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making this a lot harder than it needed to be.

All you have to do is make an image object from the resource:

```
Image img = Data.Properties.Resources.ImageFile;
```

Then after that, all you have to do is save it:

```
img.Save(@"C:\DestinationFolder\Image.jpg");
```

Now you have the file to use however you want.  It won't matter if you're in debugging or not (as far as your Application.Run location) in the event you have it in a subfolder in your project (as you should), but wouldn't necessarily have it in the same path at the end.

I was way over-thinking this the other day when I asked this question.  Hopefully I'll be able to help someone else out who's having this same issue.